# P1461 - EGR (Exhaust Gas Recycling) error, what does this mean

Tags: diesel, peugeot, egr

Each time I turn on the engine it says Depollution System Faulty, the diagnosis says "P1461 | Exhaust Gas Recycling Electric Valve Copy Signal Valve Low Limit Drift Since First Start - up ..."

[image: EGR Error message]

I Have no idea what this error means, all I know is that the EGR has a problem. Could someone explain what this error is trying to say?

Is it blocked? Should I try EGR cleaner something like [this](https://www.halfords.com/motoring/engine-oils-fluids/fuel-oil-additives/wynns-diesel-egr-valve-cleaner-150ml)

Peugeot 407, 2007.

Also done two trips on the motorway (32 miles motorway one way, so about 128 miles) and it didn't turn off so it's not the DPF I believe.

Story: Received it from the mechanic like this he said after it goes on the motorway it will be fine. There is no loss of power nor any signs of any issues from the error at the moment.

I thought it may be clogged up and really considered using the EGR cleaner from the link above due to the 57/62 reviews all saying it did well. However, I realised I don't actually understand what is even wrong with the EGR imho the error is unreadable?

Comment: I think you need to find a service manual for your car and find out the set criteria for the code and a wiring diagram. If your scanner can do bidirectional controls pull the egr valve make sure it moves as commanded and compare signal voltage to whats shown on the scan tool.

Comment: @Ben could you explain it in a less technical fashion please :) I thought the EGR valve was just a piece of metal?

Comment: @Ben Also I don't think the Car's manual mentions anything at all regarding the EGR.

Comment: The egr is a valve that now adays is electronically actuated. The code probably refers to the electronic portion of the valve. I’m guessing the code is for the position sensor, either the sensor isn’t able to sense the position of the valve. It may even refer to the valves initial resting position or learned minimum voltage. You’d want to find a document from the manufacturer that details what the computer is looking for when the code sets, as well as a way to identify the circuits to be tested.